# How to pass mongoDB query into a variable

Tags: mongodb

How can I pass the result of my MongoDB query to a const variable so it can be used globally across my application

Here is what i have tried

```
let dimension;

Settings.find({_id : "5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb"}).select('dimension').exec((err , found) =>{
   if(err){
      console.log(err);
   }else{
     dimension = found[0].dimension;
     console.log(found[0].dimension); ///here actually print out my expected result....
   }
});


console.log(dimension) /// Here prints undefined
```

Comment: Even though the dup target mentions ajax and http requests, the problem is the same here: you can't return value from an async operation like that. Your `console.log(dimension)` is executed __before__ your query success callback (callback will be executed "sometime later", because the query is async)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev then can you help me do it